# Moans to Rocky in 4 moves?

Tags: word, optimization, english, letters, word-ladder

In his novel *A Case of Need*, one of Michael Crichton's characters claims that the classic *word‑ladder*<sup>‡</sup> "**MOANS** to **ROCKY**" can be made in 4 moves (5 lines total).
But the book does not prove this and the best solution it provides is 6 moves (7 lines).

I can do it in 5 moves (6 lines) as follows:

> MOANS
>  MOONS
>  MOOKS
>  MOCKS
>  ROCKS
>  ROCKY

Can it be done in 4 moves?
If not, can that be proved?

---

<sup>‡</sup> A classic word ladder transforms the starting word to the ending word, where each move changes only one letter at a time and each move consists of a valid dictionary word.
In the absence of a free online OED, here we will stipulate that the word must be in [en.wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/) and must have been there for at least a year.
Proper nouns are not allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll attempt to prove it is not possible.

> The words MOANS and ROCKY differ by four letters. To get a 4-step word ladder, no letter can be changed twice, and every letter must therefore change directly to its final value.
>
>  Therefore there are only 4 possibilities for the second word:
>  ROANS, MOCNS, MOAKS, MOANY
>  and four possibilities for the second to last word:
>  MOCKY, ROAKY, ROCNY, ROCKS
>
>  In the last set, MOCKY and ROAKY are not words, ROCNY is only a Slovak word, so we must use ROCKS.
>  In the first set, MOCNS is not a word, and MOAKS is discounted for being a proper noun, and we cannot use MOANY since our choice of ROCKS already changed the last letter. That leaves us with ROANS.
>
>  The ladder must therefore look like:
>  MOANS
>  ROANS
>  ?????
>  ROCKS
>  ROCKY
>
>  The middle word can now only be ROCNS or ROAKS, neither of which are words.

**EDIT:**
If MOCKY is considered a word, then:

> we could choose that for the second-to-last run in the ladder. Then ROANS can't be used for the first step, leaving MOANY as the only possibility there. This gives the ladder:
>
>  MOANS
>  MOANY
>  ?????
>  MOCKY
>  ROCKY
>
>  The middle word must then be MOCNY or MOAKY, neither of which are words.

For completeness, here are all possible 4-step ladders from MOANS to ROCKY if you are not concerned whether all steps are actually words. There are $24=4!$ of them because there are $4$ changes that can be made in any order.

> ```
>  1234    1243    1324    1342    1423    1432
>  MOANS   MOANS   MOANS   MOANS   MOANS   MOANS
>  ROANS   ROANS   ROANS   ROANS   ROANS   ROANS
>  ROCNS   ROCNS   ROAKS   ROAKS   ROANY   ROANY
>  ROCKS   ROCNY   ROCKS   ROAKY   ROCNY   ROAKY
>  ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY
>  
>  2134    2143    2314    2341    2413    2431
>  MOANS   MOANS   MOANS   MOANS   MOANS   MOANS
>  MOCNS   MOCNS   MOCNS   MOCNS   MOCNS   MOCNS
>  ROCNS   ROCNS   MOCKS   MOCKS   MOCNY   MOCNY
>  ROCNY   ROCKS   ROCKS   MOCKY   ROCNY   MOCKY
>  ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY
>  
>  3124    3142    3214    3241    3412    3421
>  MOANS   MOANS   MOANS   MOANS   MOANS   MOANS
>  MOAKS   MOAKS   MOAKS   MOAKS   MOAKS   MOAKS
>  ROAKS   ROAKS   MOCKS   MOCKS   MOAKY   MOAKY
>  ROCKS   ROAKY   ROCKS   MOCKY   ROAKY   MOCKY
>  ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY
>  
>  4123    4132    4213    4231    4312    4321
>  MOANS   MOANS   MOANS   MOANS   MOANS   MOANS
>  MOANY   MOANY   MOANY   MOANY   MOANY   MOANY
>  ROANY   ROANY   MOCNY   MOCNY   MOAKY   MOAKY
>  ROCNY   ROAKY   ROCNY   MOCKY   ROAKY   MOCKY
>  ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY   ROCKY
> ```

Comment: I agree that "mocky" is not a word.  But interestingly that same "Oxford Dictionary", that gnovice used, [says it is](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mocky). Albeit a bad, bad word.  As with  gnovice's words, my print OED agrees that "mocky" is not a word.  Is that online "Oxford Dictionary" some kind of swotty *Urban Dictionary*?

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mocky) has it, too. It's just a word that, thankfully, isn't used much. I guess the character in Mr Critchton's book isn't concerned about passing valid words in word ladders and only wants to say that you can go from MOANS to ROCKY in four steps, because the O is already there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

> [MOANS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Moans)
>  [MOAKS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Moaks)
>  [MOCKS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mocks)
>  [ROCKS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rocks)
>  [ROCKY](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rocky)

However,

> "Moaks" is only an entry because it is the plural of a surname. This satisfies the standard put forth in your question, but it's unlikely this is the intended solution, if one exists.

Comment: Yeah, traditionally proper nouns are not allowed, but neither I nor the novel *explicitly* stated that; sorry.  Also, I'd say that any name that [is mostly less popular than "Gart"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Moak%2CNisha%2CGart&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMoak%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNisha%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGart%3B%2Cc0) should not be allowed irregardless. ;)  Correcting the question...

Answer (score 1):

I found one way to do it in four, if you allow some Medieval English:

> MOANS
>  ROANS: [Horses with a particular coat color pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roan_(horse))
>  ROANY: [A type of thick tar](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/roany)
>  ROAKY: [Hazy, nebulous, not clear](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.citrus.k12.fl.us/staffdev/social%2520studies/PDF/Medieval%2520English.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwismNSBta_cAhWj6YMKHVr8DnsQFjAEegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw16wdB3r2WeKvaUOkkRj-3U) or [damp, foggy, misty](https://books.google.com/books?id=v4FBAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=roaky+dictionary&source=bl&ots=NXunWSmZcU&sig=tKiHMI7PNbsUa0ED5RckbdutLHk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwismNSBta_cAhWj6YMKHVr8DnsQ6AEwBXoECAAQAQ)
>  ROCKY

Comment: Kudos, but neither ROANY, nor ROAKY are in Wiktionary ([ROANY](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roany), [ROAKY](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roaky)). Ditto my *Oxford English Dictionary* (2008 edition); so this doesn't work. Also ROANY appears to be Scottish slang, [last used circa 1809](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=roaky%2Croany&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3). There's almost no chance that Crichton referred to this.  (¿Did some shenanigans make into that online OED page?)